# SQL - Your query does not include the specified expression as part of an aggregate function

Tags: sql, ms-access, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to display data from two tables in ms access using an SQL command. I want to display the data title, forename, surname, name, type and breed. And group it by surname and name. I created the SQL command below which works fine on phpmyadmin but I get and error on ms access which is displayed below the SQL command. Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT Title, Forename, Surname, Name, Type, Breed
FROM owner, pet
GROUP BY Surname, Name;
```

Error

```
Your query does not include the specified expression 'Title' as part of an aggregate function.
```

Answer (score 4):

Any field in a `group by` query must either be in the `group by` clause, or be in an agrigation function. When field is of String type, you can use `MIN()`, or `MAX()` functions, that will give you the desired results:

```
SELECT min(Title), min(Forename), Surname, Name, Min(Type), Min(Breed)
FROM owner, pet
GROUP BY Surname, Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the GROUP BY Statement, you can only include the grouped columns along with SUM, COUNT and things like that.  These are the "aggregate functions".

In your case, Title is not one of the GROUP BY Parameters.

So, if these other columns are the same for each individual, go ahead and include them in the GROUP BY parameter list.